# Why is Ubuntu 12.04 taking very long to start and run programs?

Tags: 12.04, laptop

I have a Toshiba laptop with 2.8 gb of ram, 1.87x2 GHz processor, and Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit on it as a partition installed with wubi. It takes 5-10 mins to start up, and opening any program (such as Chromium, Chrome, Skype, Firefox, Thundermail, etc) takes over half a minute. I stopped using Unity because my graphic card couldn't handle it and swapped over to Cinnamon. It's a little better, but everything is still really really slow.

Any suggestions/solutions?

Comment: Sounds like the file system is too fragmented. How much space have you allocated to Ubuntu? What about the Windows partition, is it fragmented?

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows host drive may be fragmented. Wubi stores its data within one file on the Windows filesystem, so you can trying to use the defrag utility to defrag the wubi drive.

Hold the windows key and press <kbd>R</kbd>, and then type `dfrg.msc` into the text box and click [OK]. Then, select the drive Wubi is installed on(try the C: drive then all the other internal drives if unsure), and choose to Defragment it. Let it finish, and try booting into Wubi again.